# How to hide the HTML select arrows on Gmail email client?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select, html-email

How to hide the HTML select up-down arrows on Gmail email client?

The up-down arrows are not seen on the Chrome and Firefox browsers but they are visible on the Gmail email client. I have been trying since 10 hours but unable to hide them.

I have provided the code below.

Caret-image followed by value followed by up-down arrows:
[image: caret-image followed by value followed by up-down arrows]

I am able to hide them on Apple mail client.

```
<select id="country_code" name="country_code" form="phoneform"
                                  style="-webkit-appearance: none;
                                      -moz-appearance: none;
                                      appearance: none;
                                      -o-appearance: none;

                                      text-indent: 15px;
                                      text-align: justify;

                                      text-overflow: clip;
                                      border-radius: 0;

                                      -o-border-radius: 0;
                                      border: 1px solid green;

                                      outline: 1px solid red;

                                      background-image: url(caret-image.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(#FAFAFA, #F4F4F4 100%, #E5E5E5);

                                      background-repeat: no-repeat;
                                      background-size: 8px 6px;
                                      background-position: 5px center;
                                      background-color: white;

                                      color: #555;
                                      font-family: 'OpenSans-Light', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'sans-serif';
                                      font-size: 14px;
                                      margin: 0;
                                      padding: 0;

                                      overflow: visible;

                                      width: 65px;
                                      height: 32px;
                                  ">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="212">212</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does the `<select> ` menu and associated form work in Gmail? Generally forms generally [don't work](https://css-tricks.com/html-forms-in-html-emails/) (or at least submit data) within an email message.

Comment: Yes, It submits and does everything as expected. But I am unable to control the look of the up-down arrows on the select. It's  been more than 10 hours I have been searching but unable to find.